# Understanding char reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I've written this simple script to understand what a reference is, and I'm getting stuck on the char array.

```
int numbers[5] = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15};

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << numbers[i] << endl;
    cout << &numbers[i] << endl;
}

cout << "--------------" << endl;

char letters[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << letters[i] << endl;
    cout << &letters[i] << endl;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
3
0xbffff958
6
0xbffff95c
9
0xbffff960
12
0xbffff964
15
0xbffff968
--------------
a
abcde
b
bcde
c
cde
d
de
e
```

With the `int` array, when I use `&numbers[i]`, I receive  a strange number that is a memory location.  This is ok; it's exactly what I've understood.

But with `char`, I don't understand why I have this output.

Comment: I'm semi surprised the second part didn't break all to hell and back, considering that as far as the code says, `letters` is not nul-terminated.  But then, UB does mean "anything can happen, even the program apparently working".

Comment: @cHao: some compilers zero-initialize lots of stuff when compiling in debug mode.  Perhaps OP was "lucky".

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned this yet but this has nothing to do with references. You are talking about pointers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason is that `cout` "knows" what to do with a `char *` value - it prints the character string as a NUL-terminated C string.

The same is not true of an `int *` value, so `cout` prints the pointer value instead.

You can force pointer value output by casting:

```
cout << static_cast<void *>(&letters[i]) << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at a peculiarity of C++ streams. It tries to convert its arguments to something that is usually printable. The type of this expression is `&ints[x]` `int*`. `&chars[x]` becomes `char*` which is, incidentally also the type of a C character string. As we want this `cout << "FOO"'` to print out the whole string, it is needed to have this behavior. In your case this actually results in undefined behavior as the string you are using is not properly null-terminated. To resolve this issue use a `static_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass to `ostream::operator<<` (in fact it is a global function, not an operator) the argument of type `char*`, it is considered as a null-terminated string.

Comment: I don't the standard specifies that it must be ASCII.